# Question about this xaml markup extension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I'm trying to understand what does the markup extension for the x:Key attribute below do and what kind of markup extension is it?

```
<Window x:Class="App1.Window1" xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

<DataTemplate x:Key="{dxg:Example ResourceKey=Example}">
    <dxg:TextEdit Text="123/>
</DataTemplate>

</Window>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that example won't do anything - rather, it will fail, because isn't a markup extension named `Example` in the WPF namespace.

But if there *were* a markup extension named `Example`, what it would do is instantiate an `ExampleMarkupExtension` object, set its `ResourceKey` property, and then call its `ProvideValue` method, which would return an object that would be used as the key for the item being added to the resource dictionary.

Without more context, it's hard to know what the example you've provided is intended to show.  I'd guess that the concepts being demonstrated are a) that the key to a resource dictionary can be any object, not just a string, and b) that you can use a markup extension to generate that key.  A real example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

which adds a `DataTemplate` with a key of `typeof(TextBox)` to the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

usually the x:Key attribute allows you to reference a resource by key, in this case as the template is not within a ResourceDictionary I'm not sure it has any purpose!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,

Let's say the DataTemplate is declared in <Windows.Resources>, but the x:Key attribute is to allow other elements to reference the element to which this attribute is declared for (in this case, the DataTemplate), my question is what does this markup extension do with respect to that.

Thanks.